# Windows 8.1 Tablet settings preventing a USB boot device?

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8.1, tablet

I'm trying to get a device to boot to a Clonezilla bootable USB, but I've tried different software and none of them are allowing a Boot to anything but the primary HDD of the tablet. Here is what I'm doing:

http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/storage-files-and-folders/boot-surface-pro-from-usb-recovery-device

It acts like it's going to launch when I select the USB from the boot list, then the screen flashes and goes back to the boot list menu. Any ideas or tips to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1):

[Disable Secure Boot](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-ca/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/how-to-use-the-bios-uefi) in the UEFI.

On a Surface Pro/Pro 2 the steps are:

1. Shut down (power off) Surface.
2. Press and hold the volume-up button
   on your Surface.
3. Press and release the power button on your Surface,
   then release the volume-up button.
4. The currently configured state of
   Secure Boot (Enabled or Disabled) is highlighted. To change the
   state, tap the other one, then confirm on exit

.

Comment: Microsoft has a nasty habit of moving stuff around on their website then never handling having old links be redirected to the new location. The relevant content could easily be placed inside the answer.

Comment: This is only required to start software that is not signed with a key recognized by Secure Boot.  Windows installation disk for example are signed and you wouldn't have to disable Secure Boot to boot to it.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but I don't think Clonezilla is signed...

Comment: Its not; I just thought I would mention that.

Comment: Ideally you should have an UEFI compliant recovery flash drive, I don't know whether Clonzilla can produce that. With Macrium or AOMEI Backupper that is possible. Another solution is to use the AOMEI  OneKey. There you need no recovery device. ==> http://www.backup-utility.com/onekey-recovery.html

Comment: Thanks for the assistance guys, the secure boot setting needed to be turned off in the BIOS, now I'm running into more issues trying to get this to work, but it is definitely progress haha.